# Change textbox attributes in multiple iframes

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, textbox

The webpage I'm working on has 5 iframes and each one displays another webpage. Is there a way to change attributes of certain textboxes (such as show and hide) within all the iframes at once?

something like this:

```
$('iframe').contents().find('input[class=textboxclass]').show;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeOut(function(){   $('iframe').each(function(){
    $(this)
        .contents()
        .find('input[class=textboxclass]')
        .show();
});),3000);
```

Comment: does every input in that has class textboxclass in it?

Comment: I am not able to get the code to work. Maybe I'm just not implementing it right.

Answer (score 0):

To access the document within an `iframe` use `.contentDocument.documentElement`
and to select by class name use `input.className` or just `.className` as selector.

```
 $('iframe').each(function(){
    $(this.contentDocument.documentElement)
        .find('input.textboxclass')
        .show();
    });
```

**Note**: Of course, this has to be done after the contents in all the iframes have been loaded. Which is why I guess [Ashirvad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12059106/448232) uses `setTimeout()` although I must add it's not always reliable.

Comment: I am not able to get the code to work. Maybe I'm just not implementing it right.

Comment: @skillet: You should probably update your question with some more relevant code and what you've tried so far.